# Downthemall addon safe

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, fingerprinting

I need to download set of files, it's easy to do in queue with downthemall addon (concurrent download setting = 1) . Is it safe to get the files with addon, will it still save via Tor? Will the file fingerprints still match?
I do not download large files that affect Tor network, just small ones because I already have a slow internet connection.

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer:** Yes, it still uses Tor.

**Long answer:** I have tested this using a completely different method to the one outlined below. I just used DownThemAll! to download the [Tor Project test page](https://check.torproject.org). First, I did a baseline test using `curl` with Tor (`curl https://check.torproject.org/ -x socks5://127.0.0.1:9050 -o test_withtor.html`) and without (`curl https://check.torproject.org/ -o test_withouttor.html`), just to verify that the test page works in downloaders. The respective pages showed that they were and weren't using Tor. So that part works.

Then, I added `https://check.torproject.org/` as a DTA! download. Opened the downloaded file, and:
[image]
Success!